# Using jQuery remove() to add items. When adding back same items, class changes are preserved

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, removeclass, removeall

I have some elements in my HTML which are generated entirely by jQuery, and then removed when no longer needed.

Something along these lines:

```
var div = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'addedItem');
$('body').append(div);
```

For example, then when closed we do:

```
$('#addedItem').remove();
```

BUT... during the course of it's use, we might change the classes of `addedItem` due to adding another feature to it, for example, adding `tinyMCE` to a `textArea`

```
$('#textAreaId').tinymce({ vars });
```

Adds a rich text editor to a text area (providing all the correct scripts are loaded), I have added a new line to the end of `tinymce()`:

```
$(applyTo).addClass('editorLoaded');
```

To stop the code from trying to add the editor to the same element twice.

This all works lovely... BUT...

If I close this window down and thus call the line `$('#addedItem').remove();` and then later on (without page reload) I want to re-add to the page and display again, the classes added to the elements remain.

So, in short. An element with an ID `addedItem` is added to the `body` by jQuery, stuff is done to it and it gets a class attribute added to it. After it's finished with jQuery completely removes the element. A bit later on, we add a new element with the ID `addedItem` to the `body` using jQuery again, it's a fresh element, but yet it retains it's class attribute added before removal!

According to jQuery DOCS `remove()` behaviour should be:

> In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery
>   data associated with the elements are removed.

Which I take to mean it should remove any classes added to the elements with jQuery as well as data etc... maybe I am reading it wrong, misinterpreting, or something else!

Can anyone help me to remove these elements and ALL references to them in browser memory/cache/whatever so I can manage this issue.

jQuery version is 1.7.1 if that's any help

==========   EDIT > MORE CODE  ADDED ================

The above outlined my problem, here's the actual code then

```
// create a modal window with a top right X closer from any element
$.fn.makeModal = function (vars) {
    var theId = $(this).attr('id');
    var exists = false;
    try {
        if ($('#' + theId + '_wrap').length > 0) { // firstly check the element has already been "made modal"
            exists = true;
        };
    } catch (err) {
        exists = false;
    };

    if (!exists) { // if this is the first time
        var win = this;
        var h;
        var w;
        var persist;
        var alert;
        if (vars) {
            h = vars.height;
            w = vars.width;
            persist = vars.persist;
            alert = vars.alert;
        };
        if (typeof h == "string") {
            h = (h.replace('px', '') * 1); // clean out px if dimensions posted in px
        };
        if (typeof w == "string") {
            w = (w.replace('px', '') * 1); // clean out px if dimensions posted in px
        };
        var hRatio = 0.70;
        var wRatio = 0.5;
        var minW = 480;
        if (!h) { h = $(window).height() * hRatio }; // default case if no height passed
        if (!w) {
            w = $(window).width() * wRatio;
            minW = 480;
            if (w < minW) { w = minW };
        }; // default case if no width passed

// **** END BASIC VARIABLES

        var wrapper = $('<div/>').attr('id', theId + '_wrap').addClass('modalContainer').css({ 'top': ($(window).height() - h) / 2, 'left': ($(window).width() - w) / 2, 'width': w, 'height': h }); // create a wrapper for the main content
        var close = $('<span/>').addClass('closeModal').html('X').css({ 'z-index': getMaxZIndex() + 5 });

// creat  close button
        if (alert) {
            $(close).addClass('alert');
            $(wrapper).addClass('alert');
        } else {
            $(close).addClass('cross');
        };
        if (persist) {
            $(wrapper).addClass('persist');
        }; // persist variable allows you to determine whether to delete or simply hide element on close
        $(win).addClass('modalContent').css({ 'display': 'block', 'width': w - 20, 'height': h - 20 }).appendTo(wrapper);

        $('body').append(wrapper).opaqueBg();

        $(wrapper).prepend(close).fadeIn('fast').css({ 'z-index': getMaxZIndex() + 3 });
        $(close).modalCloser();

        $(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                closeModal(wrapper);
                $(document).unbind('keyup');
            };
        });
    } else {
        $('body').opaqueBg();
        $('#' + theId + '_wrap').fadeIn('fast') // .children().css({ 'display': 'block' });
    };
    // END OF MODAL WINDOWS
};
```

The jQuery function above creates a modal window out of any element dynamically created or otherwise.

Associated functions for closing etc:

```
//  top right X closer actions
$.fn.modalCloser = function (callBack) {
    $(this).bind('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('div.modalContainer').fadeOut(function () {
            closeModal(this, callBack);
        });
    });
};
// close modal element by item
function closeModal(ele, callBack) {
    if (!ele) {
        ele = '.modalContainer'
    };
    if ($(ele).hasClass('noClose')) {
        alert("Please wait... we're working on something.");
    } else {
    $(ele).fadeOut(function () {
        var nextZ = getMaxZIndex('.modalContainer');
        if (nextZ > 0) {
            $('#screenBlank').css({ 'z-index': nextZ });
        } else {
            $('#screenBlank').fadeOut(function () { $(this).remove(); });
        };
        if (!$(this).hasClass('persist')) {
            $(this).remove();
        };
        if (callBack) {
            callBack();
        };
    });
    };
};
// end modal window controls

// **************************************************************************************************************************************************************** 

// create opaque background for modal window to sit on
$.fn.opaqueBg = function () {
    $('#screenBlank').remove();
    var z = getMaxZIndex() + 2;
    var sb = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'screenBlank').addClass('noPrint centreLoader').css({ 'display': 'none', 'position': 'absolute', 'text-align': 'center', 'z-index': z, 'background-color': 'rgba(10, 0, 0, 0.7)', 'width': '100%', 'height': $(document).height(), 'top': '0px', 'left': '0px' });
    $('body').prepend(sb);
    $(sb).fadeIn().bind('click', function () {
        closeModal('.modalContainer');
    });
};

// find the maximum z-Index of elements on the page, used to ensure tooltips are always shown above anything else
// note, this will only work if major containing elements have explicitly set z-index
function getMaxZIndex(ele) {
    if (!ele) {
        ele = "div";
    };
    var zIndexMax = 0;
    $(ele).each(function () {
        if ($(this).css('display') != "none") {
            var z = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'));
            if (z > zIndexMax) { zIndexMax = z };
        };
    });
    return zIndexMax;
};
// end finding maximum z-index
```

So all of the above is a generic set of functions for all kinds of purposes within my project.

The particular purpose that prompted this post was creating a textarea within a modal window with `tinymce` applied, this works like this:

```
    $('#notePad .plus').on('click', function () {
        var h = $('<h2/>').html('Add Note');
        var txt = $('<textarea/>').attr('id', 'noteEditorContent').attr('name', 'newNote').css({ 'width': '100%', 'height': '400px' });
        var wrpper = $('<div/>').css({ 'width': '750', 'height': '380', 'margin': 'auto' }).append(txt);
        var button = $('<span/>').addClass('greenButton').html('Save').css({ 'float': 'right', 'margin': '40px 20px 0px 20px', 'width': '80px' }).bind('click', function () {
            saveStaffNote($('#noteEditorContent').val(), true);
        });
        var div = $('<div>').attr('id', 'notePadEditor').append(h).append(wrpper).append(button);
        $(txt).richEditor('simple', function () {
            $(div).makeModal({ 'width': '800', 'height': '530', 'persist': true });
            // CALLING THE makeModal() function above
        });
    });
```

AND FINALLY, the application of `tinymce` is this function:

```
// === loading Rich Text Editors //
$.fn.richEditor = function (theTheme, callBack) {
    var applyTo = this;
    var tinyMceVars = {
        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url: '/Admin/Plugins/richEditor/tiny_mce.js',
        // General options
        theme: theTheme,
        plugins: "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,searchreplace,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,advlist",
        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,bullist,numlist,|,undo,redo,|,code,preview,fullscreen,|,cleanup,help",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,|,insertdate,inserttime,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,search,replace",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,charmap,emotions,iespell",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,
        relative_urls: false,
        remove_script_host: false,
        document_base_url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname,
        external_link_list_url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/Admin/Scripts/Lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/Admin/Scripts/Lists/image_list.js"
    };

    if ($(applyTo).hasClass('editorLoaded') == false) {
        try { // try to apply the editor, if fails it's because the scripts are not loaded, so load them!
            $(applyTo).tinymce(tinyMceVars);
        } catch (err) {
            $.getScript("/Admin/Plugins/richEditor/jquery.tinymce.js", function () {
                $(applyTo).tinymce(tinyMceVars);
            });
        } finally { // finally apply richEdit class to avoid re-writing and perform a callback if required
            $(applyTo).removeClass('richEdit').addClass('editorLoaded');
            if (callBack) {
                callBack();
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: Interesting issue. Does it still remember the class if you leave out tinymce?

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that you're analysis of what's going on is correct.  Can you duplicate that behavior with a simple test?

Comment: *"Which I take to mean it should remove any classes added to the elements..."* No, it removes data stored in `jQuery.cache`. It doesn't touch any properties on the element, except the one that holds the `jQuery.cache` index. You need to manually remove classes.

Comment: ...if the issue is that you need to re-apply the plugin after inserting it back into the page, then try using `.detach()` instead of `.remove()`, which will retain all data when removing it, so if you insert it again, it'll still have its original behaviors.

Comment: [Here is a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iragat/1) demonstrating that when an element is removed, then the subsequent addition of an element with the same "id" value does not result in previously-added classes being restored.  Are you sure you're not adding *multiple* elements with the *same* "id" value?

Comment: Hmmm... I just tried it myself and you are correct in isolation, so it must be something else I am doing... I am definitely not adding items with the same ID... but this is definitely happening, you can see it in the Chrome Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are adding the class to a jQuery object which is also referenced by the variable called `div`. Try squirreling that variable away inside a function (javascript has function scope).

try this instead:

```
var addItem = function(){
    var div = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'addedItem');
    $('body').append(div);
};

addItem();
$('#addedItem').addClass('weeeeeee');
$('#addedItem').remove();
addItem();
```

Comment: Ahhh... could be on to something here. My full code is more complex than I post (naturally) but this *could* be the reason, I'll dig into it further! :-)

Comment: I think this is the correct answer... but I can't implement it. I am trying to create generic functions to show and hide dynamically added elements. I've re-worked things a little now so it just hides and doens't `remove()` the elements at all.

Comment: @JamieHartnoll Can you post more code? Maybe there is a way to implement something like this.

Comment: OK, I have posted my complete code. There are several functions involved to create the entire application I am working on.